# Pulling featured articles from another remote Joomla install with images via RSS or otherwise

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, view

I am looking at taking the featured articles from one Joomla site (via RSS at least) and pulling it into another Joomla site (or more). The only problem is that I require the featured article's image to appear alongside with the articles, which of course will not appear in the RSS, just the content itself.

Is there a way to override `com_content`'s feed view so then it is either in the format that I want it to be in on the second site, or is there yet another method (like an API) that could be used for pulling in that content?

Edit: I did look at [the Joomla! community blog article on overriding code](http://community.joomla.org/blogs/community/521-did-you-know-overrides-are-not-just-for-html.html), but it is from about 5 years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say with 100% certainty that this will work as I've not used it on the file you're interested in, but I've been able to override everything I've wanted to so far without hacking the core Joomla code.:

- Read [How to override the component mvc from the Joomla! core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core)
- Try [this plugin](https://gist.github.com/dongilbert/3237387)

Once you've have the plugin figured out, you'll see that you can copy the file that formats the RSS into a folder of your choosing within the plugins folder, and when the plugin itself fires, it will locate and use your copy of it instead of the original.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that you could pull any things from RSS feeds into your Joomla site. I used obGrabber and it is my suggestion!